# How to add the certificate for the Confluent Platform in a SSO environment

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, single-sign-on, confluent-platform

I'm setting up a Docker container of the Confluent Platform, and I'm getting the javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException error. Which certificate do I add?

The reason why I'm using Docker is due to my laptop being a windows device. I've installed the latest version of Java/cloned the latest images for the Confluent Platform.

I've added the certificate for "*.confluent.io" into cacerts for my JRE.

I think this issue is due to my environment being a closed Single Sign On environment. So this is where I am stuck.

The specific error message that I get when setting up docker compose with the CP image is

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Error: Unknown error
ERROR: Service 'connect' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:latest' returned a non-zero code: 7
```

This is the error I get when I use

```
curl  https://api.hub.confluent.io/api/plugins

curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

Comment: Are you sure that the root CA "DigiCert Global Root CA" is in the trusted CA of JRE? I think you have to import that certs into cacerts and not the server certificate...